# Meteor live templates and pure JS variables

Tags: meteor

I have the following very simple Meteor app:

in tags.html

```
<body>
  {{> tags}}
</body>

<template name="tags">
  <input type="button" id="submit" value="Change tag" />
  {{tags}}
</template>
```

...and in tags.js

```
var tags = 1;

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.tags.tags = function() {
        return tags;
    };

    Template.tags.events({
        'click #submit': function() {
            console.log("You pressed the button");
            tags += 1;
        }
    });
}
```

When I start the app I get a button and the initial value of the var tags (1) right next to it, which is correct.
Then when I click the button the value of tags increases (I can check in the console), but the template does not re-render.
Is this normal behavior? I am not sure what should I expect - could not find anything in the documentation that would tell me when exactly does the live template gets re-rendered.

If I change the var to use the Session object however:

in tags.html

```
<body>
  {{> tags}}
</body>

<template name="tags">
  <input type="button" id="submit" value="Change tag" />
  {{tags}}
</template>
```

...and in tags.js

```
var tags = Session.set("tags", 1);

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.tags.tags = function() {
        return Session.get("tags");
    };

    Template.tags.events({
        'click #submit': function() {
            console.log("You pressed the button");
            Session.set("tags", Session.get("tags") + 1);
        }
    });
}
```

... all works fine.

Can anyone shed some more light?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal. The relevant documentation is [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#reactivity):

> the reactive data sources that can trigger changes are:
>
> - Session variables
> - Database queries on Collections
> - Meteor.status
> - Meteor.user
> - Meteor.userId
> - Meteor.loggingIn

Comment: Thanks a lot Sjoerd. Looking forward to meeting you guys at The Hague Meteor meetup :-)